# Using same postgres container for a spring project database and a keycloak database

Tags: spring, postgresql, docker, keycloak

I am trying to run three dockerized services:

1. Spring-boot app
2. Keycloak for authentication
3. Postgres as database

I would like to have both the Spring-boot app and the Keycloak app to use the same Postgres container as their database, but I couldn't find a way to make it work. My docker-compose.yml is as follows:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  db:
    image: 'postgres:13.1-alpine'
    container_name: db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./app_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data_app
      - ./keycloak_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data_keycloak
      - ../docker-postgresql-multiple-databases:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES: keycloak, app_user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:14.0.0
    container_name: keycloak
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin
      - DB_VENDOR=postgres
      - DB_ADDR=postgres
      - DB_USER=keycloak
      - DB_PASSWORD=password
      - JDBC_PARAMS=useSSL=false
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
    healthcheck:
      test: "curl -f http://localhost:8080/auth || exit 1"
      start_period: 20s

  app:
    image: 'app.postgre:latest'
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: app
    depends_on:
      - db
      - keycloak
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/app
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=app_user
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=password
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update
volumes:
  app_data:
  postgres_data:
```

(Note: I tried using the following code: https://github.com/mrts/docker-postgresql-multiple-databases to set-up the needed databases by hand, but even so it still fails. I also tried doing without this script, but that also failed.)

I have tried them and managed to make a docker-compose file which runs the spring app and the database together, and another docker-compose file which runs the keycloak app and the database together, but when I try to bring all three together it fails.

Comment: Is it strictly necessary that the databases for keycloak and the app are written do separate files?

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what happens?

Comment: What is in your `../docker-postgresql-multiple-databases` ? It must be a directory with  scripts that contains `CREATE USER` and `CREATE DATABASE` statements.

Answer (score 1):

I have a very similar setup with Postgres, Keycloak, pgAdmin and a Golang API service. The skeleton of my `docker-compose.yml` is like this, give it a try (I omitted some parts for simplicity), it is working for me. I think the important parts here are `networks` and `links`, and also setting up multiple databases (as you already do). I use `db` as the hostname of Postgres server, when I connect to it via pgAdmin for example.

```
services:  
  db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.db
    volumes:
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    restart: unless-stopped      
    ports:
      - ${POSTGRES_PORT}:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES=${POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    healthcheck:
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
    volumes:
    ports:
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - db     
  api:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.api
    ports:
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST=${POSTGRES_HOST}
      - POSTGRES_PORT=${POSTGRES_PORT}
    volumes:
    networks:
      - mynetwork  
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
    restart: unless-stopped
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
    environment:
      - DB_VENDOR=${KEYCLOAK_DB_VENDOR}
      - DB_ADDR=${KEYCLOAK_DB_ADDR}
      - DB_DATABASE=${KEYCLOAK_DB_DATABASE}
      - DB_USER=${KEYCLOAK_DB_USER}
      - DB_SCHEMA=${KEYCLOAK_DB_SCHEMA}
      - DB_PASSWORD=${KEYCLOAK_DB_PASSWORD}
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=${KEYCLOAK_USER}
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=${KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - ${KEYCLOAK_PORT}:8080
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    links:
      - db
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
volumes:
networks:
  mynetwork:
```

And some important a values from my `.env`:

```
POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES=mydb,keycloak
POSTGRES_USER=
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=
POSTGRES_HOST=db
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
KEYCLOAK_PORT=8084
KEYCLOAK_DB_VENDOR=POSTGRES
KEYCLOAK_DB_ADDR=db
KEYCLOAK_DB_DATABASE=keycloak
KEYCLOAK_DB_USER=
KEYCLOAK_DB_SCHEMA=public
KEYCLOAK_DB_PASSWORD=
KEYCLOAK_USER=
KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=
```

My `Dockerfile.db` is like this, you don't need the `localedef` part (I need it for Hungarian localization):

```
FROM postgres:latest
RUN localedef -i hu_HU -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias hu_HU.UTF-8
COPY docker-postgresql-multiple-databases.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

And `docker-postgresql-multiple-databases.sh` contains:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -u

function create_user_and_database() {
    local database=$1
    echo "  Creating user and database '$database'"
    psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" <<-EOSQL
        CREATE USER $database;
        CREATE DATABASE $database;
        GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE $database TO $database;
EOSQL
}

if [ -n "$POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES" ]; then
    echo "Multiple database creation requested: $POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES"
    for db in $(echo $POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES | tr ',' ' '); do
        create_user_and_database $db
    done
    echo "Multiple databases created"
fi
```

Comment: The difference is that here postgresql is built from `Dockerfile.db`. I suppose that all inititalization scripts are COPYed during  docker build. And OP uses  image  'postgres:13.1-alpine'. I think your answer is incomplete without Dockerfile.db

Comment: Oh, you are right, thanks, I will edit my answer.